# c# public function defined and used in other functions

Tags: c#, function, listener

Hey all i have the following code:

```
 namespace testingLeap
 {
  class Program : Listener
  {
    GestureListener listener;
    Controller controller;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        listener = new GestureListener(500);
        listener.onGesture += listener_onGesture;
        Controller controller = new Controller(listener);
```

I am wanting to share the **listener** and the **controller** with other static void functions within the program.. however, doing the above i get errors:

*An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'testingLeap.Program.listener'*

What would i be doing incorrect? I know in VB this works:

```
Dim listener As New GestureListener(500)
Dim controller As New Controller(listener)

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   listener.onGesture += listener_onGesture
End Sub
```

Comment: The code that you have won't compile as it stands.  You won't even be able to access `listener` from `Main` as it's not static and you have no instance.  Note that the two programs you've shown are radically different contexts.  The VB function you've shown isn't `static` (`shared` in VB).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to use `static` modifier for `listener` and the `controller` if you want to use them in `static` methods

```
static GestureListener listener;
static Controller controller;
```

read more : [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx.aspx)

Comment: That was it! Thanks for the help, Mehran.

Answer (score 2):

You can mark the field as `static` or pass around a containing class.

`static` field:

```
static GestureListener listener;
```

or maybe some kind of factory method if you intend to have different kinds.

```
public interface IGestureListenerFactory
{
    GestureListener GetGestureListener(int arg);
}

public class GestureListenerFactory : IGestureListenerFactory
{
    private static readonly object Locker = new object();
    private static readonly Dictionary<int, GestureListener> _listener = new Dictionary<int, GestureListener>();

    public GestureListener GetGestureListener(int arg)
    {
        GestureListener listener;

        if(!_listener.TryGetValue(arg, out listener))
        {
            lock(Locker)
            {
                if(_listener.ContainsKey(arg))
                    return _listener[arg];

                listener = new GestureListener(arg);
                _listener.Add(listener);
            }
        }

        return listener;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for also providing a reply, Romoku.